# Flask - Pass data from different functions to same template

Tags: python, flask

So basically I have two functions

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def do_stuff1():
    *LOGIC*
    return (render_template('index.html', data=data))
```

and

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def do_stuff2():
    *LOGIC*
    return (render_template('index.html', moreData=moreData))
```

How do I pass through the data from the second function to the the same template because it's not working as I have specified there. I'm only getting the first functions data.

EDIT: I should have specified that I want to use the data within the same route.

Comment: The 2 functions share the same route. To reach the second one, attach it to a different route.

Comment: But I want to use both of them within the same route. I'd prefer to keep the logic separated hence the two different functions? If this is possible.

Comment: `data` and `moreData` should be produced by two standard (undecorated) functions. Then write a third method with the `app.route` decorator that calls each of them and merges their returns.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Appreciate both of your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second function does not have to be a 'view' but just a plain python function. Unless I'm missing something...

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def do_stuff1():
    *LOGIC*
    moreData = do_stuff2()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data, moreData=moreData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Only wish I would have seen this about 6 hours earlier!